# Hibernate how delete rows with null colums in join table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

i have a problem in Hibernate.

I have 2 classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="grupos")
public class Group implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;
private String nombreGrupo;


@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name="grupos_usuarios",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="grupo_id"),inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="usuario_id"))
private Set<Usuario> usuarios = new HashSet<Usuario>();
```

and the other class..

```
@Entity
@Table(name="usuarios")
public class User implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id; 
private String nombreUsuario;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY ,mappedBy="usuarios")
private Set<Grupo> grupos = new HashSet<Grupo>();
```

So im using a join table.A group can have multiple users and one user can have multiple groups.The problem is when i try to delete a group

```
ERROR: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`pfc`.`grupos_usuarios`, CONSTRAINT `FK_2pjiv067qnbhmbgjt35vogy93` FOREIGN KEY (`grupo_id`) REFERENCES `grupos` (`id`))
```

For example,if I delete a group,i dont have to delete the users(is the reason why im not using cascade.remove).In this case,if I delete a group, there are rows in the join table with null colums.I suppose this is the reason of the error.Is possible to delete this rows ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error is explained in the exception message:

> a foreign key constraint fails (`pfc`.`grupos_usuarios`, CONSTRAINT `FK_2pjiv067qnbhmbgjt35vogy93` FOREIGN KEY (`grupo_id`) REFERENCES `grupos` (`id`))

You're trying to delete a group to which users belong. So either you decide this should not be possible (and the error is a good thing), or you decide that the users should first be removed from the group, and you have to explicitely do it before removing the group:

```
group.getUsuarios().clear(); // removes all the users of this group
session.delete(group);
```

EDIT:

To delete a user, you also need to remove the association. Since `group.usuarios` is the owner side of the association, that's the side that must be modified. Clearing `User.grupos` is not sufficient:

```
for (Group group : user.getGrupos()) {
    group.getUsuarios().remove(user); // removes all the associations between the user and its groups
}
user.getGrupos().clear(); 
session.delete(user);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.i was wrong,yes,i can delete a group.the problem is when i try to delete a user(the inverse side) im trying all kind of solutions,but always i get the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

sounds good.but i got the same error.
maybe i will try to create two one@many relationship instead of many@many relationship.or i can use xml instead of annotations(with xml many@many works better?)i can read in internet some persons with the same problem